# Uniformly Distributed Random-Variable With Specific Ordering

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations, uniform-distribution, combinatorial-proofs

Let $0\leq a<b$.  Define the subset of $[a,b]^n$ by
$$
X=\{(x_1,\cdots,x_{n-1})\mid b^{2n}\geq x_1^{2(n-1)}\geq\cdots\geq x_{n-1}^2\geq a\}
$$

What is the probability that a uniformly distributed random-vector in $[a,b]^n$ is an element of $X$?  *ie: Obeys that ordering?*

Comment: *So far..I only can note that: If the powers of $2$ are omitted that this quantity is equal to $\frac1{(n-1)!}$.*

Comment: Note that the volume will be $(b-a)^n \times P(X)$ so if there's any geometry to the set it'll be easier to think of it that way.

Comment: Consider $n=2$, in which case $$X=\{x_1 \mid b\geq x_1^{\frac1{2^{}}}\geq a^{\frac1{2^{1}}}\}=\{X_1\mid b^2\geq x_1\geq a\}.$$ So $$P(X)=\frac{(b^2-a)(b-a)}{(b-a)^2}=\frac{b^2-a}{b-a}\neq\frac{1}{(2-1)!}.$$ What did I miss?

Comment: Oh, I was mostly refering to the case where $b\leq x_1\leq a$ and no roots were considered.

Comment: $X$ is a subset of $[a,b]^{n-1}$ but your random variable lives in $[a,b]^n$

Comment: I corrected, it for them.  
Whatever it is, the result should be bounded above by $\frac{(b-a)^n}{(n-1)!}$

Answer (score 1):

This is difficult because of the descending powers, but it can be done ***inductively***.  First, note a couple of boundary cases:

- If $b^{2n} < a$, then the probability is zero.
- If $b>1$, then the particular constraint $b^{2n} \geq x_{1}^{2(n-1)}$ holds no matter what.

To focus on the induction argument, let's simplify things for now by letting $a=0$ and $b=1$.

.

**Case $\mathbf{a = 0, \ b = 1 }$**:

Take any $c \in [0,1]$, then:
$$ P(c \geq x_{1}^{2} \geq 0) = c^{1/2} $$
Here's the ***inductive step***:
$$ P(c \geq x_{1}^{4} \geq x_{2}^{2} \geq 0) = \int_{0}^{c^{1/4}} P(t^{4} \geq x_{1}^{2} \geq 0) dt $$
That is, we are integrating $x_{1}$ from $0$ to $c^{1/4}$. This evaluates to:

$$= \int_{0}^{c^{1/4}} t^{4(1/2)} dt = \left[ t^{4(1/2 + 1/4)} \right]_{0}^{c^{1/4}} \cdot \frac{1}{4(1/2 + 1/4)} = c^{1/2 + 1/4} \cdot \frac{1}{3}$$

(I am purposely not simplifying the fractions, they will reveal a pattern.)

Let's do one more iteration before figuring out the inductive pattern.
$$ P(c \geq x_{1}^{6} \geq x_{2}^{4} \geq x_{3}^{2} \geq 0) = \int_{0}^{c^{1/6}} P(t^{6} \geq x_{1}^{4} \geq x_{2}^{2} \geq 0) dt $$
Which evaluates to:
$$ = \int_{0}^{c^{1/6}} t^{6 \cdot (1/2 + 1/4)} \cdot \frac{1}{3} dt = \left[ t^{6(1/2 + 1/4 + 1/6)} \right]_{0}^{c^{1/6}} \cdot \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{6(1/2 + 1/4 + 1/6)} = c^{1/2 + 1/4 + 1/6} \cdot \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{5.5}$$

Okay, so here is ***the pattern*** when $a=0$ and $b=1$:
$$ P(c \geq x_{1}^{2(n-1)} \geq \ldots \geq x_{n-1}^2 \geq 0) = c^{Q_{n}} M_{n} $$
Where:
$$Q_{n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{2k} \quad \text{and} \quad M_{n} = \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \big( 2(k+1)Q_{k} + 1 \big)^{-1} $$
This follows inductively because:
$$Q_{n} = Q_{n-1} + \frac{1}{2(n-1)} \quad \text{and} \quad M_{n} = M_{n-1} \big( 2nQ_{k} + 1 \big)^{-1} $$

Setting $c = b^{2n} = 1$, yields:

$$ P(b^{2n} \geq x_{1}^{2(n-1)} \geq \ldots \geq x_{n-1}^2 \geq 0) = b^{2nQ_{n}} M_{n} = M_{n}$$

Hence, $M_{n}$ is the answer when $a = 0$ and $b = 1$!

.

**Case $\mathbf{a = 0, \ b \leq 1}$**: 
We have to scale by $b^{-1}$ every time we integrate, so:

$$ P(b^{2n} \geq x_{1}^{2(n-1)} \geq \ldots \geq x_{n-1}^2 \geq 0) = b^{2nQ_{n}} M_{n}b^{1-n} $$

This can be rewritten as the final answer: $b^{1+n(2Q_{n} - 1)} M_{n}$.

.

**Case $\mathbf{a \geq 0, \ b \leq 1}$**:
Nothing conceptual has changed, just the lower integration bound is now: $a^{1/2}$, $a^{1/4}$, $a^{1/6} \ldots$. Also, we have to scale by $(b-a)^{-1}$ every time we integrate.
$$ P(c \geq x_{1}^{2} \geq a) = \left[c^{1/2} - a^{1/2}\right] (b-a)^{-1}, \quad c \in [a,b^{4}]$$
$$ P(c \geq x_{1}^{4} \geq x_{2}^{2} \geq a) = \int_{a^{1/4}}^{c^{1/4}} P(t^{4} \geq x_{2}^{2} \geq a) (b-a)^{-1} dt, \quad c \in [a,b^{6}]$$
$$ = \left[c^{3/4}/3 - a^{3/4}/3 - a^{1/2}(c^{1/4} - a^{1/4}) \right] (b-a)^{-2}$$

I don't have a closed form pattern for this case, but the inductive step is still perfectly valid. So, you could write Mathematica code to compute this out to any $n$. Once $n$ is sufficiently large that $b^{2n} < a$, the expression will become negative, and the correct probability is zero.

.

**Case $\mathbf{0 \leq a \leq 1, \ b \geq 1 }$**: Again, the inductive approach is still valid, but now the probabilities are going to be piecewise functions.

$$P(c \geq x_{1}^{2} \geq a) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      \left[c^{1/2} - a^{1/2}\right] (b-a)^{-1} & c \in [a,b^{2}] \\
      1 & c \in [b^{2},b^{4}] 
\end{array} 
\right. $$
$$ P(c \geq x_{1}^{4} \geq x_{2}^{2} \geq a) = \int_{a^{1/4}}^{c^{1/4}} P(t^{4} \geq x_{2}^{2} \geq a) (b-a)^{-1} dt, \quad c \in [a,b^{6}]$$

.

**Case $\mathbf{1 \leq a < b }$**: Because $1 \leq a$, the powers of $a$ are increasing, which affects bounds. The following math is nearly identical to the previous case just with a couple lower bounds changed.
$$P(c \geq x_{1}^{2} \geq a) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      \left[c^{1/2} - a^{1/2}\right] (b-a)^{-1} & c \in [a^2,b^{2}] \\
      1 & c \in [b^{2},b^{4}] 
\end{array} 
\right. $$
$$ P(c \geq x_{1}^{4} \geq x_{2}^{2} \geq a) = \int_{a}^{c^{1/4}} P(t^{4} \geq x_{2}^{2} \geq a) (b-a)^{-1} dt, \quad c \in [a^{4},b^{6}]$$

.

**Conclusion**: We have closed-form expressions for when $a=0$ and $b \leq 1$. For all of the other cases, the boundaries become messy. Fundamentally, the *inductive step* still works, and it can be used to compute the answer for any fixed $n$.

Comment: It would still be nice to have closed-form in general tough

Comment: Yeah, I can't think of a simple combinatorial solution or anything.  I agree there probably is a closed-form solution. 

It'd be messy, there would be at least another summation on the outside, and probably some min/max cutoffs on the inside.  We'd have to conjecture a closed-form and verify it inductively.  Computing a couple more examples in the general case might reveal a pattern.

Comment: Actually, the most important case for me is $0\leq a< b\leq 1$, if you have an idea of how to compute that one; it would be great; could we do it by rescaling?  Unfortunately writing code for it would kinda defy the point, since I'm looking for something computationally efficient for each $a \in [0,1)$.

Comment: Cool, I'll try to edit it this week.  Finding the pattern there is definitely doable since it is just integrating polynomials and there are no repeated cutoffs in that case.  (Only one cutoff at the very end.)

Comment: Thanks, that would be awesome! :D)